# Is the latency set in a pipeline the max or the sum value?

Tags: gstreamer

I read that the latency in a pipeline is configured via a query and that the latency value is set as a “max”:

> Before the pipeline goes to the PLAYING state, it will, in addition to selecting a clock and calculating a base-time, calculate the latency in the pipeline. It does this by doing a LATENCY query on all the sinks in the pipeline. The pipeline then selects the maximum latency in the pipeline and configures this with a LATENCY event.
>
> All sink elements will delay playback by the value in the LATENCY
> event. Since all sinks delay with the same amount of time, they will
> be relatively in sync.

https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/application-development/advanced/clocks.html?gi-language=c#latency-compensation

If a pipeline has two jitter buffer elements with respective latency values of 50 and 100:

```
                   RTPJitterBuffer    RTPJitterBuffer
                     latency=50         latency=100

|-------------|    |-------------|    |-------------|
|             |    |             |    |             |
|          src| -> |sink      src| -> |sink      src| -> 
|             |    |             |    |             |
|-------------|    |-------------|    |--------------
```

The pipeline will query 50 and 100.

Is the latency set on the sink's 100 (max) or 150 (sum)?

If my understanding of timestamps is right, it has to be a sum as some sinks can see timestamps delayed by 150 as a worse case. However, I suppose sink's can also only query upstream and set the sum value for themselves.

Any insights here would be solid : )